# How can I setup an MX record so that *.mydomain.com will point to my mailserver but mydomain.com will use Google apps?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, mx-record

I would like to use google apps for my domain e-mail.

However, I want to be able to process emails and store attachments like in a ticketing system sent to:

mailbox@*.mydomain.com

How can I setup the MX records for this? Are there services that already do this that I can leverage?

My options are either to poll it from an inbox with pop3/imap or to process it in real time by running my own mailserver (the latter is not preferable due to the difficulty/responsibility involved).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would believe that entries like this would work:

```
@ IN MX 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
* IN MX 10 mailserver.mydomain.com.
```

I haven't tried it, but based on doing this with other record types, it should work.

Comment: That does work, I've had to do it before.  Oh the spamanity!